# Environment Agency - API

Tags: jquery, json, api

I would like to create a simple web based tool to request Enviroment Agency (EA) data via their API.
Their instructions are here:
http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference

I would like to use jquery if possible.

My question is:
Does the link above provide enough information to complete my task? The reason I ask is I am struggling to get started with this task.

I would expect to write something as follows to count the number of entries for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring', //not sure if this link is correct
    type: 'GET', 
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.length+' package(s) found')
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Failed to get the list of packages.')
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpcallback'
});
```

The link above does not appear to provide such instructions.
I have emailed the EA to ask for example code but it appears they don't have any.

Any feedback on whether the link above is missing critical instructions to link to their API would be greatly appreciated. If the answer is yes, then I know to keep asking the EA for more instructions.
Otherwise more reading for me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: look at http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/doc/reference#api-requests where they use the url http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floods

Comment: Don't use jsonp, server doesn't handle it. See example using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/52jk5o8n/1

Answer (score 0):

The response data is an object, not array.
So, `data.length` does not work.
Try `Object.keys(data)` and you will see that you have the data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/data/readings?latest',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        var keys = Object.keys(data);
        var size = keys.length;
        console.log('number of keys: ' + size);
        if (size) {
            keys.map(function(key, i){
                console.log('key: ' + key);
                if (key == '@context') {
                    console.log('  ' + data[key]);
                }
                else if (key == 'meta') {
                    console.log('  ' + JSON.stringify(data[key]));
                }
                else if (key == 'items') {
                    console.log('data[items][0]:');
                    console.log('  ' + JSON.stringify(data[key][0]));
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error('Failed to get the list of packages.')
    }
});
```